# Uncaught TypeError: counterElement is null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I'm creating a shopping cart for a website and I've encountered an error. I need to add a unit to the number of this product when adding the same product. But for some reason I get an error when I add the same product, although logically everything should work. Java script can't find my [data-counter]. and returns null even though it finds the number of the first item. Help me please. My code:
JS:

```js
const cartWrapper = document.querySelector('#check');

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.hasAttribute('data-cart')) {

    const card = event.target.closest('.dlg-modal')
    console.log(card)
    //Собираем данные
    const productInfo = {
      id: card.dataset.id,
      imgSrc: card.querySelector('.gui__pizzablock').getAttribute('src'),
      title: card.querySelector('.productTitle').innerText,
      price: card.querySelector('.priceTitle').innerText,
      description: card.querySelector('.gui__description').innerText,
      counter: card.querySelector('[data-counter]').innerText,
    };

    console.log(productInfo)
    const itemInCart = cartWrapper.querySelector(`[data-id="${productInfo.id}"]`);

    console.log(itemInCart)
    if (itemInCart) {
      alert('present')

      const counterElement = itemInCart.querySelector('[data-counter]');
      counterElement.innerText = parseInt(counterElement.innerText) + 1;
      alert('wow')

    } else {

      const cartItemHTML = `<div class="item__block">
                <div data-id="${productInfo.id}"></div>
                <div data-counter>${productInfo.counter}</div>
            <img class="img__rubb" src="${productInfo.imgSrc}">
            <p style="margin: -73px 100px">${productInfo.title}</p>
            <p class="description__rubb" style="margin: 81px 100px">${productInfo.description}</p>
            <hr style="width: 400px; margin: -55px 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(103,103,103,0)">
            <p style="margin: 70px 15px">${productInfo.price}<span>руб.</span></p>
         </div>`;
      cartWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cartItemHTML)

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div data-id="01" id="modal_1" class="dlg-modal dlg-modal-fade">
  <div class="gui_pizza">
    <img class="gui__pizzablock" src="ciplenokBarbekku.webp">
    <div class="gui__pizza__constructor">
      <p class="productTitle">Chicken</p>
      <div class="kupiudauna" data-counter>228</div>
      <!--            change1-->
      <p class="gui__description"><span id="pizza_sm" class="gui__description">30</span> см, <span id="pizza_testo" class="gui__description">традиционное тесто</span>, <span id="pizza_g" class="gui__description">710</span> г</p>
      <!--               change1-->
      <div class="gui__main__description">
        <p>Sause, sause, sause,<br class="show_pizza__space">cheese, meat</p>
        <!--               change2-->
        <input type="radio" class="big__small__pizza" id="one" name='radio' />
        <input type="radio" class="big__small__pizza" id="two" name='radio' />
        <input type="radio" class="big__small__pizza" id="three" name='radio' />
        <input type="radio" class="big__small__pizza" id="four" name='radio' />
        <input type="radio" class="big__small__pizza" id="five" name='radio' />
        <!--               chabge2-->
        <br />
        <div class="big__small__pizza__buttons">
          <!--               chabge3-->
          <label id="onebtn" class="big__small__pizza__btn" for="one">Small</label>
          <label id="twobtn" class="big__small__pizza__btn" for="two">Average</label>
          <label id="threebtn" class="big__small__pizza__btn" for="three">Big</label>
          <!--               chabge3-->
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 15px 0" class="big__small__pizza__buttons__tonkoe">
          <!--                  change4-->
          <label id="tradis" class="big__small__pizza__btn__tonkoe" for="four">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Традиционное</label>
          <label id="tonkoe" class="big__small__pizza__btn__tonkoe" for="five">&nbsp;Тонкое</label>
          <!--                  chabge4-->
        </div>
        <!--               change5-->
        <div id="first_gui_block" class="gui__pizza__block">
          <!--                    change5-->
          <div class="game__block__content">

            <div style="font-size: 22px; padding: 13px 0px" class="game__mode">Add&nbsp;по&nbsp;</div>
            <!--                     change6-->
            <img id="selected1" class="selected1" src="selected.png" style="width: 29px; height: 29px">
            <!--                     change6-->
            <br>

            <br>

            <img class="show_pizza__1__gui" src="x2cheese.png" style="width: 85px; height: 85px">

            <p class="show_pizza__1_text__gui">CheeseX2</p>
            </img>
            <p class="show_pizza__1_text__gui2">3,00$.</p>

          </div>
          <div class="game__block__content">

          </div>
        </div>
        <!--               change7-->
        <div id="second_gui_block" class="gui__pizza__block2">
          <!--                  change7-->
          <div class="game__block__content">

            <div style="font-size: 22px; padding: 13px 0px" class="game__mode">&nbsp;</div>
            <!--                     change8-->
            <img id="selected2" class="selected2" src="selected.png" style="width: 29px; height: 29px">
            <!--                     change8-->
            <br>
            <br>
            <img class="show_pizza__1__gui" src="ogurchiki.png" style="width: 85px; height: 85px">
            <p class="show_pizza__1_text__gui3">Cucumbers</p>
            </img>
            <p class="show_pizza__1_text__gui4">2,00$.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="game__block__content">

          </div>
        </div>



        <div style="color: #0077FF; font-weight: lighter;" class="small__bigger__pizza__btn">
          <em>⠀</em>
          <a class="small__bigger__pizza__btn" style="color: white;" data-cart target="_blank">Add&nbsp;to&nbsp;basket&nbsp;за&nbsp;<span class="priceTitle" id="price__pizza__gui">2.90</span>$.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="closer" data-close=""></span>
  <h3></h3>
</div>

<div data-id="999" id="check" class="dlg-modal dlg-modal-fade" style="background: #f3f3f3; width: 790px; height: 100%; left: 100%">
  <h2 style="text-align: left; padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px">Your basket</h2>
  <div class="item__block__container">


  </div>


  <span class="closer1" data-close=""></span>
</div>
```

I tried even the most stupid solutions, by type to change the type of quotes. I'm suffering for a long time, I can not solve this problem, please help

Comment: The `data-counter` element isn't inside the `data-id` element. They're siblings. So `itemInCart.querySelector('[data-counter]')` doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Barmar what do I need to do so that data-counter doesn't return null?

Comment: `counterElement = itemInCart.nextElementSibling`